# Deleting a file from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a class that calls a *BroadcastReceiver*. I am struggling to delete a file when it's called.

If I use `deleteFile("file.txt")` within the class it works and deletes the file.

However if I try `deleteFile("file.txt")` within the BroadcastReceiver class it won't work.

Any ideas on how I can delete a file within a BroadcastReceiver class? I have tried many different ways and I an guessing there is something fundamental I'm missing.

Comment: If the error generated an exception in logcat, please post it along with the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: Posting your `BroadcastReceiver` class would help others see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteFile()` is [a method on `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile%28java.lang.String%29). While `Activity` and `Service` inherit from `Context`, `BroadcastReceiver` does not.

Instead, call `deleteFile()` on the `Context` passed into `onReceive()`.

Comment: thank you! fixed with

`context.getApplicationContext();
context.deleteFile("aa.txt");`